# A Theorem from Algebra by Martin Isaacs

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$\boldsymbol{Theorem}\Longrightarrow$ Let $|G|= p^{3}q$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes, then either $G$ has a normal Sylow-$p$-subgroup or a normal Sylow -$q$-subgroup or $p=2$ and $q=3$ and $|g|=24$

$\boldsymbol{My~}$$\boldsymbol{Question\Longrightarrow}$ Does this
theorem means the following

(A) A group order $24$ has no Sylow subgroups ?

(B) A group of order $24$ is simple?

If not , please describe what does exactly the theorem says in the
form of equivalent statements or in any other way.

Comment: Isaac Martin $=$ Martin Isaacs?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have edited it

Comment: The conclusion does not **necessarily** hold for a subgroup of order $24$. For example, it holds for any abelian group of order $24$ (since all subgroups of an abelian group are normal), but it does not hold for $S_4$, which has three subgroups of order $8$ and four subgroups of order $3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (A) A group order $24$ has no Sylow subgroups ?

No. Every finite group has Sylow $p$-subgroups for every prime $p$ dividing the order.

> (B) A group of order 24 is simple?

No. If it is abelian, then it cannot be simple because its order isn't prime. And the smallest nonabelian simple group has order $60$.

A group of order $24$ can have lots of structures. You can see all of them catalogued [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_24). Some of them have normal $p$ or $q$ sylows, and some of them do not.

The theorem simply cannot assert the impossibility of having four $3$-Sylows and three $2$-Sylows itself.

According to Bungo's comment below, the symmetric group on $4$ elements, $S_4$ is already an example of a group with no normal Sylow subgroups. While I trust that already, you can corroborate that [with these details](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S4#Quick_summary) on the groupprops wiki.

Comment: So what does the theorem mean? or you want to say book is wrong.

Comment: @KislayTripathi Can you be more specific about what you think would be wrong? Isn't "it has a normal Sylow, or else it has order $24$" already very clear?

Comment: I don't know.The book can not be wrong as it belongs to a prestigious author.The problem is with my understanding.Can you please state what does the theorem  say exactly.

Comment: @KislayTripathi Did you get the idea somewhere along the line that "no normal Sylows $\implies$ simple?"  That is false, but being simple implies having no normal Sylows, of course.

Comment: @KislayTripathi Well, books by famous authors can still contain mistakes, but I don't see any here. I just explained what I think the theorem says above: it has a normal Sylow or it has order $24$. What is mysterious?

Comment: it appears to me that theorem says it has normal sylow subgroup otherwise it's order is 24 which implies group of order 24 has no normal sylow subgroups which implies it has no normal subgroup which implies it is simple bcoz every normal subgroup is sylow subgroup

Comment: A normal sylow subgroup means a unique sylow subgrpup

Comment: @KislayTripathi Well... there you go, it's just like I said. "no normal Sylows" does not imply "No normal subgroups." That just does not follow.

Comment: "Every normal subgroup is a Sylow subgroup" is false. For example, take any abelian group; all of its subgroups are normal.

Comment: @rschwieb No need to reach for a semidirect product; $S_4$ is a counterexample :-)

Comment: @Bungo Oh good :) We should use that then!